# Bad Argument Error with Erlang spawn_link/3

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to write a Qsort function that sorts parallely, and a direct translation of this code to Elixir works, but for some reason, when I run `pqsort:pqsort([5, 4, 3, 10, 1]).` it fails with this error:

```
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  spawn_link/3
        called as spawn_link(pqsort,#Fun<pqsort.0.102886275>,[<0.33.0>,[3,2,1]])
     in call from pqsort:pqsort_worker/2 (pqsort.erl, line 6)
```

Here's my code:

```
-module(pqsort).
-export([pqsort/1, pqsort_worker/2]).

pqsort_worker(Listener, []) -> Listener ! {self(), []};
pqsort_worker(Listener, [H | T]) ->
    PID_1 = spawn_link(pqsort, fun pqsort_worker/2, [self(), [ X || X <- T, H >= X ]]),
    PID_2 = spawn_link(pqsort, fun pqsort_worker/2, [self(), [ Y || Y <- T, H < Y ]]),
    receive
        {PID_1, List_1} ->
            receive
                {PID_2, List_2} -> Listener ! {self(), List_1 ++ [H] ++ List_2}
            end;
        {PID_2, List_2} ->
            receive
                {PID_1, List_1} -> Listener ! {self(), List_1 ++ [H] ++ List_2}
            end
    end.

pqsort(List) -> element(2, pqsort_worker(self(), List)).
```

Comment: You do realize this is a massive pessimization compared to qsort?

Comment: Yeah... This is more just me experimenting with Erlang parallelism. I didn't really intend this to be any faster. I was just mostly messing around.

Comment: The title change makes the question totally different. Check the typespec of spawn_link/3: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn_link-3 The second argument is an atom, not a fun. Funs have arity and are already built -- Erlang lets you use the function's label + list of args (the length of which determines arity) to call functions on the fly anywhere a `{Mod, Fun, Args}` type value is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn-3), you will notice that the second argument is not a function but an atom

Just change

```
PID_1 = spawn_link(pqsort, fun pqsort_worker/2, [self(), [ X || X <- T, H >= X ]]),
PID_2 = spawn_link(pqsort, fun pqsort_worker/2, [self(), [ Y || Y <- T, H < Y ]]),
```

to

```
PID_1 = spawn_link(pqsort, pqsort_worker, [self(), [ X || X <- T, H >= X ]]),              |(emacs@Mac-mini-de-Rodrigo)1> c("/Users/rorra/erlang/pqsort", [{outdir, "/Users/rorra/erlang/"}\
PID_2 = spawn_link(pqsort, pqsort_worker, [self(), [ Y || Y <- T, H < Y ]]),
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you! Could you maybe explain the difference? I thought that all first class functions had to be qualified with the `fun` keyword.

Comment: @ChristopherDumas when you go to the documentation: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn-3
You will notice that the second argument its not a function but an atom.
If my answer addressed the question, feel free to accept it as the right answer for the question, thank you :)

Comment: I really like your answer. Maybe could you add your explanation to the actual answer for future people?